# Javascript array.reduce() function

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

can someone tell me why?? why swapping parameters is changing outputs
The function which is passed on to reduce does'nt actually has a name but . why swapping its parameter is changing the output?

```
const array = [

  {
    username: "john",
    team: "red",
    score: 5,
    items: ["ball", "book", "pen"]
  },
  {
    username: "becky",
    team: "blue",
    score: 10,
    items: ["tape", "backpack", "pen"]
  },
  {
    username: "susy",
    team: "red",
    score: 55,
    items: ["ball", "eraser", "pen"]
  },
  {
    username: "tyson",
    team: "green",
    score: 1,
    items: ["book", "pen"]
  },

];


const reducearray=array.reduce((user,sum)=>{return sum+user.score;},0);
//gives [object Object]undefined 

const reducearray=array.reduce((sum,user)=>{return sum+user.score;},0);
//and this gives the right answer ......
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Parameters are ordered in JS. `reduce` docs say that parameters to the callback are `(accumulator, element, index)`. What makes you think changing the order _shouldn't_ affect the output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First parameter of the reduce should be the initial value or the returned value from function. This is the reason for getting result in second syntax.

Answer (score 1):

The first parameter to reduce is the accumulator and it is important to keep the order.

While in your case, the first parameter is an interger starting with 0, the second one is an object obtained by iteration on `array`.

Please do check the docs for [**Array.prototype.reduce on MDN**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)